# Android Bitmap multithreaded processing - not thread-safe?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, image-processing, thread-safety

I want to process a bitmap in my Android application - the bitmap can be huge, so I use multithreading to perform faster operations. Here's my code (part of Runnable child):

```
@Override
public void run() {
    int imageHeight = filter.getBitmap().getHeight();
    int start = threadNumber * imageHeight / threadCount;
    int stop = (threadNumber + 1) * imageHeight / threadCount;
    for (int j = start; j < stop; j++) {
        filter.processLine(j);
    }
}
//...
protected void processLine(int lineNumber)
{
    int width = bitmap.getWidth();
    int pixels[] = new int[width];
    bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, lineNumber, width, 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        pixels[i] = processPixel(pixels[i]);
    }
    bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, lineNumber, width, 1);
}
```

When I use only 1 thread in the pool, everything works properely. Unfortunetely, when I use thread number equal to number of cores of the processor (4 in my device) the result is like following (for grayscale filter):

[image: issue]

It looks like sometimes:

- bitmap.getPixels(...) does not work, as there are black lines in the output
- bitmap.setPixels(...) does not work, as there are unchanged lines in the output

Am I right? Are these functions thread-unsafe? How should I perform multi-thread bitmap filtering to be fast and thread-safe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2D image processing in Android is provided by the Skia library, also used by Chrome.

It's hard to find a definitive answer. "Skia is not thread-safe, although SkBitmap [used by Bitmap] *is* thread-safe..."  I don't know what to think.  I perused a bunch of inscrutable JNI/C++ code and this is the best I can offer (which seems to be more than anyone else can do):

I think you should call `bitmap.getPixels()` on the *entire bitmap*.  Then divide up the resulting array and thread out the processing.  When all the threads are completed, re-assemble the results and call `bitmap.setPixels()`

It seems like `bitmap.getPixels()` and `bitmap.setPixels()` should be nothing more than `memcpy()`s, but there is a lot more going on under the hood with reference counts, image caches, color space conversions, premultiplications and who knows what else.  Taking the `Bitmap` methods out of concurrent processing should keep you out of trouble.

Comment: This is my final answer. ) Deleting my earlier one.

Comment: I have tried your solution with `bitmap.getPixels()` but it also didn't work properly - there were fragments with unprocessed image. Unfortunately, I reverted changes with this. Maybe later I will write this code again and show the output.

Comment: And when you do, please post the code that executes the threads also.  Cheers

Comment: Sorry, solution with `getPixels` for whole image works good, apparently I've made a mistake first time. A disadvantage of this method is big memory consumption. It would be perfect to do filter "in place", without any copy, but using "getPixel" and "setPixel" is obviously bad idea and these are very slow. Is there any better solution besides using Android NDK?

Comment: I think the NDK might be the way to go.  You could look for a third-party 2D image processing library, but you'd still have to copy the pixels into a Bitmap so a user can see an image.  Sigh.

Comment: Solution with synchronized parts is many times slower than single thread processing. Please edit your post again and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: As I suspected it would be.  Thanks